# IJavaEditorTextHover changes text only on method hover - java plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I´m developing a Java plugin and recently I thought of showing a new text in the hint box when the user positions his cursor over a method name.
I know I can change the text by creating a class like this:

```
public class ExtensaoMostraExcecoesOnMethodHover implements org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.java.hover.IJavaEditorTextHover{

    @Override
    public String getHoverInfo(ITextViewer textViewer, IRegion hoverRegion) {
        return "it´s a small world after all";
    }
}
```

but this changes the text in the hint box for all selections. I want to change only when the user selects a method name.

Does anyone know how to do this? Can anyone show me some good tutorials about how to implement IJavaEditorTextHover?